# Partial specialization syntax confusion

Tags: c++, templates

To define a specialization that is used for every Vector of pointers and only for
Vectors of pointers, we need a partial specialization:

```
 template <class T> class  Vector <T *> : private Vector<void *> {
 public:
      typedef Vector<void*> Base;
      Vector(): Base() {}
      explicit Vector(int i) : Base(i ) {}
      T *& elem(int i ) { return static_cast <T *&> (Base::elem(i)); }
      T *& opeator[](int  i) { return static_cast <T *&>(Base::operator[](i )); }
      //...
 };
```

This definition has me in a tizzy. This is related to partial specialization but i don't  understand the syntax. `private Vector<void *>` definition part looks like a parent class to me.

1. Why not specify `Vector <void *>` in  `template <class T> class Vector <void *>`.
2. It would be great if anybody can  breakdown the definition part. (sorry if its too much to ask)

Comment: Your snippet is illegal and has other syntax errors.  Could you please double-check and show us the Real Code?

Comment: This is code sample  taken from  bjarne stroutroup's book. Its in section 13.5 ( specialization )  in Template chapter.

Comment: Nah, it's a mis-typed copy of a code sample from one of Bjarne's books.

Comment: The C++ programming language, third edition, is what i am reading. I matched the code and they look same. what is  illegal here?

Comment: The `static_cast`s are illegal between these types, and `opeator[]` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the inheritance, which has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Partial specialization means that you make a new template from an existing one which is more specialized, but still generic, by matching a more restrictive pattern. The general pattern of your example is like this:

```
template <typename T> class Foo;      // primary template

template <typename U> class Foo<U*>;  // partial specialization

template <> class Foo<fool>;          // full specialization
```

The first line is the primary template and matches *everything* that is not matched by a more specialized form. The third line defines an actual *type* (not a template!) `Foo<fool>` (for some given type `fool`). The middle line, on the other hand, is still a template, but it only matches a type of the form `T = U *`, i.e. a pointer:

```
 Foo<char> x;   // uses primary template with T = char
 Foo<fool> y;   // uses full specialization (nothing to be matched)
 Foo<int*> z;   // uses partial specialization, matching U = int
```

About the `Vector<void*>`: It just turns out that the author chooses to define the partially-specialized `Vector<U*>` as deriving from a fixed class `Vector<void*>` (which would have to be fully specialized elsewhere).

Comment: Where does `Vector<bool*>` come into it?

Comment: I don't see `Vector<bool*>` anywhere in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Neither do I see it in the answer! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about template specialization, and that's what's going on here.

This is a template class definition of a `Vector<T>` being specialized for a pointer type T. Presumably, you've defined the `Vector<T>` template elsewhere, so this code is only specializing it for the circumstance where T is a pointer. Hence the `Vector<T*>`.

Since it is a specialization, the `Vector<T*>` derives from the Vector 'base-template', which is a `Vector<void *>`. The other code, which isn't detailed in your example, would handle specifics of working with a pointer type as the contained data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is making the members of `Vector<Ptr>`, for any pointer type, forward to `Vector<void*>` (using a combination of inheritance and explicit base calls plus casting).  This prevents the compiler from making many identical versions of the same code, differing only by the pointer type, possibly saving space in the final executable (although most linkers are smart enough to combine identical functions, see for instance "COMDAT folding")

This is problematic according to the Standard because the pointers don't have the same alignment restrictions.  Not all object pointers necessarily have the same size in a conforming implementation.  In fact, I'm very surprised that the compiler accepts `static_cast<T*&>(a_void_ptr)` at all.  Static casting between `void*` and `T*` is allowed of course, but this deals with reference-to-pointer types, which are unrelated.  It should require `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @DeadMG: The only rule that implies equal size is "Converting a prvalue of type "pointer to `T1`" to the type "pointer to `T2`" (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value." and it only applies to pointers with the same alignment requirement.  I've heard tell of systems where a `char*` requires extra bits compared to an `int*`.  More importantly, the encodings can be different, which invalidates the cast used here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the author of the code wants to exploit the fact that the code for different pointer types is identical. It is probably just a premature optimization to reduce code size, or "code bloat". The idea is most likely that each new pointer type will only add a layer of static_cast to the void pointer code.

Comment: The idea is that layer gets inlined and optimized to nothing at all.  But as I said in my answer, this is actually not valid.

Comment: Sure. I guess the assumption is fine for most 32/64-bit x86 compilers, but to be strictly correct the size should be added as a template parameter with default value sizeof(T*).